# Power BI with Python Visuals

Tags: python, powerbi, seaborn

I'm using python to create visuals. Am I able to use pandas groupby() function to create aggregation dataframe within the visuals code editor or do I have to create an unconnected satelite table in the data model to create the visual? The problem with the latter method is that the visual doesn't update with the dashboard's filter context.

Thanks in advance

**Update**

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

data = dataset.groupby(by = ['Last Balance Range'])['Last Balance Range'].count().reset_index(name='Arrears')

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
sns.set_color_codes("pastel")
g = sns.barplot(x=data['Arrears'], y=data['Last Balance Range'], data=dataset, label="Total", color="b")
```

The above is the code I used to generate the python visual.

[image: PBi python visual]

This was the resultant visual.

Comment: Would this not depend on many more factors than just the data model? Have you tried any of these setups for yourself? If so where there any things you encountered?

Comment: Hi there. I've updated my question with a bit more info regarding what steps I took to generate the visual. Thanks